# Resolution in Fedora MATE-Compiz Desktop 37 with AMD GPU via HDMI Stuck at 1024x768

Tags: fedora, gnome, resolution, mate-desktop, amd-graphics

Version and Desktop Information:

> Fedora Release 37

> Kernel Linux 6.0.7-301.fc37.x86_64 x86_64

> Mate 1.26.0

lspci | grep VGA shows this:

> Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX >470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] (rev c3)

Display panel shows Monitor:Unknown as seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

Resolution is stuck at 1024x768 as stated in the title. Xorg config file appears to be blank.

Using the same version of Fedora but with the gnome desktop, resolution can be changed and monitor is detected with no issue.

I believe the difference has to do with the DE, but I am not certain what that difference may be and I've found no solid indication as to what it may be either.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but unfortunately I don't see anything I recognize as being directly related to the issue posted above? I did see one referencing an issue with any kernel after 5.10, but I am not sure that's related here as the above issues manifests itself when using MATE but does not manifest when using gnome.

Comment: You're right, this could be a Mate specific issue. Look for their bug tracker then. I wasn't attentive when reading your question, sorry.

Comment: I would have thought so too, but I was able to replicate the behavior on XFCE and one or two other DE's as well. I am back on MATE and trying to avoid gnome if at all possible, but I am struggling with locating anything definitive.

Also, I don't see anything "amd" related to this specific issues on the MATE github.

Comment: What does `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` or the Wayland equivalent tell you? With Gnome, is that via a previous install? It does sound like the kernel module is not being loaded.

Comment: Sounds like this is an issue with X11 instead of Wayland?